# Setting up Split View Controller Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Im getting really stuck on how to implement a split view controller in Xamarin ios. I have put the split view controller into the storyboard but have done no coding because I don't even know how to reference the master and detail views in the C# code. All the tutorials I have searched through are either in swift or objective-c for obvious reasons.

If I do find an xamarin tutorial then its all done through XAML which i'm not using as its not cross platform. I really need help on just getting the basics of the split view controller set up such as populating the tableview in the master view with the different pages I need.

Hopefully someone can give me a basic run through of getting the very basics set up please.

Many Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/tvos/user-interface/split-views?tabs=vsmac).

First, add SplitViewController to storyboard,  then name `MasterViewController` and `DetailViewController` as below,  it will create class file automatically in your application folder, so you can write reference code in it.

[image]